# Simple doubt on a linear algebra proof involving inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, absolute-value

From Lang's Introduction to Linear Algebra (1985), page 27:

> Theorem 4.2: Let $A, B$ be two vectors in $R^n$. Then $|A·B|\le||A||\
>  ||B|| $.
>   Proof: Let $c=(A·B)/(B·B)$. We write $$A=A-cB+cB$$ By
>   Pythagoras, $$||A||^2=||A-cB||^2+||cB||^2=||A-cB||^2+c^2||B||^2 $$
>   Hence $c^2||B||^2\le||A||^2$ (and the proof continues)

My doubt is, where exactly does $c^2||B||^2\le||A||^2$ come from? Shouldn't the sign be $\ge$, since $||A||^2=||A-cB||^2+c^2||B||^2$ and $||A-cB||^2$ is always greater than or equal to zero, so that $||A||^2\le c^2||B||^2$? Thanks.

Comment: $||A||^2$ is the sum of two positive things, so it is larger than either of those things.

Comment: It would've probably been helpful if you had read from page 26 to the theorem, where this is almost the entire focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $\|A-cB\|^2$ and $c^2\|B\|^2$ are nonnegative and they add up to $\|A\|^2$. Therefore none of them is greater than $\|A\|^2$ itself and so each quantity must be at most $\|A\|^2$.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\|A\|^2 = \|A - cB\|^2 + c^2 \|B\|^2 \geq 0 + c^2\|B\|^2$$
so indeed, $\|A\|^2 \geq c^2\|B\|^2$.